# How to use d3.js in Phoenix?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I'm trying to convert a Ruby on Rails + d3.js app to Elixir on Phoenix + d3.js.  I cannot seem to get d3.js to load properly.

I have it in web/static/vendor/js/d3.v3.min.js. And my brunch-config.js has an order before section like this:

```
order: {
 before: [
   "web/static/vendor/jquery.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/jquery.bootgrid.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/moment.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/fullcalendar.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/d3.v3.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/sugar-full.min.js",
   "web/static/vendor/js/waves.js"
 ]
}
```

I have a template with a script tag which contains the d3 javascript.  However, it errors with:

```
graph:259 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you confirm in your network/resource tab that `d3.v3.min.js` is indeed loaded?

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a security restriction in your browser that is preventing D3 from being downloaded correctly.

The best thing to do is to get the D3.JS and associated scripts manually, then place them in the same folder as your graph/web page source code.

What you then need to do is find the .. tags in the HTML that reference the D3.JS and other files, and change them to just be the name of the associated files you copied to your HTML pages folder.